# mv: cannot stat 'wordpress/': No such file or directory

Tags: server, apache2, 19.04, wordpress, vps

I am stuck. For two days I have been trying to install Wordpress on my VPS (Ubuntu 19.04). Everything is going well to the point where I want to move wordpress to a "wordpress" folder. Both folders and WordPress are on the server, but I still get the message: No such file or directory (see below). Does any of you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your time and efforts!
Chris

...
*

```
wordpress/wp-admin/post-new.php
wordpress/wp-admin/themes.php
wordpress/wp-admin/options-reading.php
wordpress/wp-trackback.php
wordpress/wp-comments-post.php
root@vmd47899:/tmp# ls
latest.tar.gz
systemd-private-d7728dd88f924cbcb407473d102a460b-apache2.service-d0hP9f
systemd-private-d7728dd88f924cbcb407473d102a460b-systemd-logind.service-ZTJTaf
systemd-private-d7728dd88f924cbcb407473d102a460b-systemd-resolved.service-SzR3tg
systemd-private-d7728dd88f924cbcb407473d102a460b-systemd-timesyncd.service-Jhjp1i
wordpress
root@vmd47899:/tmp# cd wordpress/
root@vmd47899:/tmp/wordpress# ls    
index.php    wp-activate.php     wp-comments-post.php  wp-cron.php        
wp-load.php   wp-settings.php   xmlrpc.php
license.txt  wp-admin            wp-config-sample.php  wp-includes
wp-login.php  wp-signup.php
readme.html  wp-blog-header.php  wp-content            wp-links-opml.php  
wp-mail.php   wp-trackback.php
root@vmd47899:/tmp/wordpress# cd ..
root@vmd47899:/tmp# mv wordpress/* /var/www/html/
root@vmd47899:/tmp# mv wordpress/* /var/www/html/wordpress
mv: cannot stat 'wordpress/*': No such file or directory
root@vmd47899:/tmp# mkdir /var/www/html/wordpress
root@vmd47899:/tmp# mv wordpress/* /var/www/html/wordpress
mv: cannot stat 'wordpress/*': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

After you ran your FIRST `mv wordpress/* /var/www/html/` command (which moved all the files, directories and other filesystem objects in the `wordpress` directory to `/var/www/html/`) there was nothing left in `wordpress` for your subsequent commands to `mv`.

Also, please learn how to format code with the `{}` tool - it makes fixed-width computer text easier to read.

Comment: @chris-danneffel waltinator's answer explains why. It appears however that you tried to copy the contents of `wordpress/*` to two locations, in this case you might want to use `cp -Rp` instead of `mv`